# Xcode FIRRemoteConfig Build error

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-remote-config

In my xcode project, `firebase realtime database` and `Analytics` already implemented and working successfully. To implement, `Firebase remote config` feature, I added `FirebaseRemoteConfig.framework` and `Protobuf.framework` into my project. I am getting build error with following message. I have not write any code yet related with remote config.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_kFIRAppIsDefaultAppKey", referenced from:
      +[FIRRemoteConfig(FIRApp) receivedReadyToConfigureNotification:] in FirebaseRemoteConfig(FIRRemoteConfig+FIRApp_718fa6fc16d7fc9251249ec4e3a58ce2.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is all framework that I added into my project.
[image]

Comment: Have you got any solution ?

Comment: not yet. i still stuck here. then i stop importing remote config framework. waiting for response

Comment: I have found solution of this issue. First you need to add all the updated frameworks of firebase. If you are using it. In my case I was having older version of firebase sdks. I just updated it & error went off.

Comment: its works. thanks man. put your answer, i want to give you some credit by clicking accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found solution of this issue. First you need to add all the updated frameworks of firebase. If you are using it. In my case I was having older version of firebase sdks. I just updated it & error went off. Happy Coding :)